# Working with functions using modulo operator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I have a function defined in a computer program that I would like to study mathematically:

$y = \frac{x}{2} + (\frac{5}{2}x + 1)*(x\%2)$

This function is used on strictly positive integers and also returns integers only.

The main issue is that it's using the modulo operator ($\%$) as part of the function calculation, not as in a modular equation, and I have no clue how to translate into a formula that is suitable for mathematical analysis...

I have found various topic related to modulo/floor and how to translate them into mathematical form:

- [Solving equations involving modulo operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396763/solving-equations-involving-modulo-operator)
- [Solving modular equations with a variable in the modulus divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355955/solving-modular-equations-with-a-variable-in-the-modulus-divisor)
- [How to represent the floor function using mathematical notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389063/how-to-represent-the-floor-function-using-mathematical-notation/389115#389115)

But none of them seems to match this particular situation.

Also, to clarify what I mean by "studiy mathematically", it would be for example to determine the range of output values if input values are taken in a given range, or to determine limits/periodicity if this function was called recursively.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: It was in C++, I do not see how this would impact the answer though as the modulo operator should always have the same result on positive integers, independently of the language :)

Comment: I hope you find a solution to it! Sorry I can't help you there.

Comment: $x\%2=x-k\cdot2$, where $0<k<x$. Then $y=y(x,k) = \frac{x}{2} + (\frac{5}{2}x + 1)\cdot(x-k\cdot2)$.

Comment: @Dmitry That sounds correct, but there is even more conditions on $k$ than $0<k<x$, not all integers in this range would lead the the correct result, only the highest integer so that $k \cdot 2 \leq x$

Comment: $n$%$2 = (1-(-1)^n)/2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x % 2` is equivalent to $\frac{1-(-1)^x}{2}$.  On positive integer $x$, `x % 2`${}\in \{0,1\}$.  (Some programming languages do stupid things for negative $x$.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202131/modulus-operator-incorrect-for-negative-numbers/29202167).)  Consequently, you have
$$  y = \begin{cases}
x/2 &, \text{$x$ even}  \\
3x + 1 &, \text{$x$ odd}
\end{cases}  \text{.}  $$
The [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) covers the study of this function under recursion.

Comment: Okay this helped a lot, so the new expression becomes

$y = \frac{x}{2} + (\frac{5}{2}x + 1)*(\frac{1-(-1)^x}{2})$

This can harldy be generalized for any kind of modulo, but at least it helps with my problem so I will mark this as the accepted answer for now.

Comment: @Flo : The Question does not ask for a version for general modulus.  Try $$ x \pmod{n} = \frac{n-1}{2} - \frac{n \arctan(\cot(\pi (x+1/2) / n))}{\pi}  \text{.}  $$